# NodeId as string in ModelCompiler OPC UA

Tags: github, deployment, opc, opc-ua

I am trying to develop a OPC UA server on my own, but since I am quite a newbie in coding, it is quite hard for me.
I have started from the QuickstartApplication found here: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET-Legacy

in particular I edit the ModelDesign.xml file to customize it as I wish
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET-Legacy/blob/master/ComIOP/Common/Common/ModelDesign.xml

I would like to define some nodes with NodeId as string (all the NodeId in the ModelDesign.xml in the example are numeric)
Following this xsd, I have found "StringId" and "NumericId" that look like what was looking for
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/blob/master/ModelCompiler/UA%20Model%20Design.xsd
but changing their value in ModelDesign.xml does nothing about the NodeId. There is no error, just the compiler assigns new NodeIds (all numeric) as if it does not consider the changes I have made.

As a compiler, I am using the ModelCompiler found on GitHub 
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler

Can somebody help me, please? How can I customize the NodeId of the nodes?

Thank you
Edo

Comment: Just general tip, when you write "I tried ABC" it is good to include actual content, when you write "nothing seems to work" what it means exactly? What was the error message? Or there was no error? Help others to help you.

Comment: thank you astrowalker, I'll add details

Answer (score 0):

the best suggestion that I can offer at this stage is to clone the `UA-.NETStandard` and run the NetCoreConsoleServer in

```html
UA-.NETStandard/SampleApplications/Samples/NetCoreConsoleServer
```

through the debugger. The boiler node manager, if my memory serves me well, uses stringIDs. The Interface INodeIdFactory in ISystemContext.cs offers some insight in how ID's are generated.

IMHO, the model designer has no switch to enforce string ID's [as you know](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/issues/23). So you'll need to programmatically allocate stringID's rather than numeric ID's to nodes upon server boot. I haven't figured it out yet either.

So, you may set breakpoints in the `BoilerNodeManager.cs` and see how the nodeID is actually constructed.